# Nextjs 13 - Refresh SSG Issue

Tags: javascript, next.js, netlify, next.js13

I'm experiencing some issues with refreshing data on a simple data page. The scenario is straightforward: I have a page that displays category data and another page that edits the same data. When I edit and redirect back to the list page, I want the list to update with the new data. Since it's a Static Site Generation (SSG) page, it's built at build time, resulting in static data.

```
import prismadb from "@/lib/prismadb";
import CategoriesClient from "./components/client";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export default async function Categories(res) {
  let categories;
  categories = await prismadb.category.findMany({
    orderBy: {
      createdAt: "desc",
    },
  });

  const formattedCategories = categories.map((category) => ({
    id: category.id,
    name: category.name,
    isActive: category.isActive,
  }));

  return (
    <>
      <CategoriesClient data={formattedCategories} />
    </>
  );
}
```

```
  async function onSubmit(data) {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      if (initialData) {
        await axios.patch(`/api/categories/${params.categoryId}`, data);
      } else {
        await axios.post(`/api/categories`, data);
      }
      router.refresh();
      router.push(`/categories`);
      toast.success(successMessage);
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error(`An error as occurred: ${err.response.data}`);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

I've tried using the revalidate property on the list page, but it only works with a hard refresh and not with the router, which I'm using.

```
export const revalidate = 1;
```

Currently, I have force-dynamic to make the page dynamic. The problem is that when I redirect to the page using the router or Next.js Link, it works fine. However, when I manually refresh the page with F5 or enter the link manually, I get a 500 error (only when I'm on prod environment, in Netlify. on local machine works fine).

Is there a way to solve this issue and ensure that the page updates correctly in all scenarios, including manual refreshes?

Can you please help me on this problem. I'm stuck on this for days..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the purposes of Static site generation is speed, by having a ready page to be presented to the client when he requests it. And next/router doesn't make a hard reload to preserve the single page application properties.

So, I think you have 2 solutions here:
1- keep the static site generation and make the changes in the client-side, along with invoking a revalidation for this page.
You can do this using a revalidation api instead of using revalidate key, like this example

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  // Check for secret to confirm this is a valid request
  if (req.query.secret !== process.env.MY_SECRET_TOKEN) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token' })
  }
 
  try {
    // this should be the actual path not a rewritten path
    // e.g. for "/blog/[slug]" this should be "/blog/post-1"
    await res.revalidate('/path-to-revalidate')
    return res.json({ revalidated: true })
  } catch (err) {
    // If there was an error, Next.js will continue
    // to show the last successfully generated page
    return res.status(500).send('Error revalidating')
  }
}
```

And call this api whenever the user makes changes that will impact the page
You can check the full details here
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration
And then in the client-side, use the useEffect hook and call the data api inside it with and empty dependency array, to get invoked on router refresh

2- use server-side rendering instead of static generation if the modifications are frequent

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I tried to implement the first solution you gave me, but when I deploy it to Netlify, it gives an error when invoking the API. After doing some research, it turns out that Netlify still doesn't support the res.revalidate function. That's probably why the force-dynamic option was causing some issues as well. I had to go with the second option and fetch the data in SSR (Server-Side Rendering)...